# Django (DRF) ORM - Simple left join with reverse relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am trying to select data from my postgreSQL database using Django 3.2.9 and DRF 3.12.4.

Here are my models :

```
class Headpiece(ValidatedModelbase):
    class Types(models.TextChoices):
        POWDER = "Powder"
        SOLUTION = "Solution"

    id_headpiece = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(null=False)
    structure = models.TextField(null=False)
    total_structure = models.TextField(null=False)
    molecular_weight = models.FloatField(null=False)
    type = models.CharField(null=False, choices=Types.choices, max_length=255)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "headpiece"
        managed = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class Matter(ValidatedModelbase):

    id_matter = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    dna_tag = models.ForeignKey(DNATag, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    headpiece = models.ForeignKey(Headpiece, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True, related_name='matter')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "matter"
        managed = True
```

```
class Vial(ValidatedModelbase):

    id_vial = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rack = models.ForeignKey(Rack, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    matter = models.ForeignKey(Matter, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='vial')
    barcode = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
    position_column = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    position_row = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    quantity_left = models.FloatField(null=False)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    reserving_business_entity_name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)
    origin_name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "vial"
        unique_together = ["rack", "position_column", "position_row"]
        managed = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.barcode
```

The data i need is a list of Headpieces, joined with their Vials data. I want a new line for each Vial, and if no Vial is related, the Headpiece data only.
In SQL, it translates to this :

```
SELECT headpiece.*, vial.*
FROM headpiece 
LEFT JOIN matter on matter.headpiece_id = headpiece.id_headpiece
LEFT JOIN vial on vial.matter_id = matter.id_matter
LIMIT 100
```

This query results in exactly what i need my API to return.

Here is how i am querying with DRF at the moment :

```
def get_headpiece_vials_filtered(serializer: GetMatterListSerializer) -> dict:

    # page = serializer.validated_data.get("page")
    # limit = serializer.validated_data.get("limit")
    # order = serializer.validated_data.get("order")
    # filters = serializer.validated_data.get("filters")

    queryset = Headpiece.objects.select_related(
                    'matter__vial',
                ).filter(
                    id_headpiece=5, matter__vial__id_vial=4525,
                )

    print('count')
    print(queryset.count())
    print(queryset.query)

    return queryset.all()

    return queryset.all()
```

Then calling this function in a controller, but i'm actually just logging things for now. :

```
def get(self, request: Request) -> Response:
        """
        Get Headpiece List filtered
        """
        serializer = GetMatterListSerializer(data=request.query_params)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            headpieces = get_headpiece_vials_filtered(serializer)
            print(headpieces)
            return Response(data=headpieces, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Here is the traceback i am getting :

```
Internal Server Error: /vials/headpiece
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jhaensler/dnastorage/Back/NovalixBackend/controllers/Headpiece/HeadpieceController.py", line 49, in get
    headpieces = get_headpiece_vials_filtered(serializer)
  File "/home/jhaensler/dnastorage/Back/NovalixBackend/services/domain/HeadpiecesQuery/GetHeadpieceVialsQueries.py", line 27, in get_headpiece_vials_filtered
    print(queryset.query)
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 265, in __str__
    sql, params = self.sql_with_params()
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 273, in sql_with_params
    return self.get_compiler(DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS).as_sql()
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 513, in as_sql
    extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 55, in pre_sql_setup
    self.setup_query()
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 46, in setup_query
    self.select, self.klass_info, self.annotation_col_map = self.get_select()
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 248, in get_select
    related_klass_infos = self.get_related_selections(select)
  File "/home/jhaensler/miniconda3/envs/dnastorage/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 985, in get_related_selections
    raise FieldError(
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'matter'. Choices are: (none)
```

The actual query i am trying to build is :

```
SELECT headpiece.*, vial.*
FROM headpiece 
LEFT JOIN matter on matter.headpiece_id = headpiece.id_headpiece
LEFT JOIN vial on vial.matter_id = matter.id_matter
where vial.id_vial=4525
LIMIT 100
```

I guess i am struggling because of the reverse relationship, although I might be wrong, I think this is a pretty standard way of organizing data with SQL.

I know i could use raw SQL, but i'll need to apply a good amount of filters, pagination, and ordering to the query, it will be much easier using the ORM. Also, i'll be surprised if there was no solution to this using the Django ORM.

Comment: If you use `.values(..)` there is no need for `.select_related(..)`. But using `.values(..)` in the first place is actually an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of combining [**`.values(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#values) and [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filter) together: the `.values(…)` will make `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s since the items can be `NULL` whereas the `.filter(…)` sees that the result is non-`NULL`, so it optimizes it away to `INNER JOIN`s.

But actually you should (probably) not use `.values(…)` in the first place: it is kind of an [antipattern <sup>[Django-antipatterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html):

```
queryset = Headpiece.objects.select_related(
    'matter__vial',
    'matter__vial__rack',
    'matter__vial__project',
).filter(id_headpiece=5, matter__vial__id_vial=4525)
```

based on the query however, you should not prefetch the `rack` and `project` either, so:

```
queryset = Headpiece.objects.select_related(
    'matter__vial',
).filter(id_headpiece=5, matter__vial__id_vial=4525)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Placing `.values(..)` at the end of the querySet (as mentioned in your comment) solved the unwanted additional join problem. 
Now, removing said `.values(..)` results in a new error : `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'matter'. Choices are: (none)` 

Is there a way to keep using methods on the Headpiece model (to follow your antipattern guide), and be able to add filters on the related tables ?

Comment: @JulienHaensler: that makes not much sense since `.values(..)` and `.select_related(..)` act independent of each other (in fact that is partly the problem). Can you edit the question with the queryset you are using now (and perhaps also the post-processing where the problem might occur) and the full traceback?

Comment: I have updated the question with the traceback and actual code used now

Comment: @JulienHaensler: ah, but your model indeed has no `ForeignKey` from `Headpiece` to `matter`. In that case Django refuses to work with JOINs, since that is bad query design: you use `.prefetch_related` then which will make two queries, one to fetch the `Headpiece`s, and one to fetch the related items. This will reduce the bandwidth, and is how it works for all one-to-many (and many-to-many) relations.

Comment: Headpiece to Matter is a one to one relationship. It is actually just used as a pivot from Headpiece to Vial, which is a one to many relationship (one headpiece many vials). I am just trying to get a list of headpieces, join the vial information. If a headpiece has multiple vials, have multiple results in consequence.
This is a plain left join, i don't get why it is not possible with Django. Am i going in the right direction with trying to use QuerySet or should i use Serializers ? I also need to filter and paginate the results.

Comment: @JulienHaensler: then change `headpiece = models.ForeignKey(...)` to `headpiece = models.OneToOneField(...)`. This will add a uniqness constraint to the field, and thus prevent that the same `Headpiece` is referenced twice or more by different `Matter`s.